# Drop down Menu on CSS

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Drop Down Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506571/css-drop-down-menu)

I am trying to create a drop down menu (on the navigation bar), but I have not been able to do so yet (yes, I am new to CSS and HTML).. So, far, I have the following in CSS:

```
#navbar ul { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 5px; 
list-style-type: none; 
text-align: center; 
background-color: #000; 
} 

#navbar ul li {  
display: inline; 
} 

#navbar ul li a { 
text-decoration: none; 
padding: .2em 1em; 
color: #fff; 
background-color: #000;
}
```

Then, I have the following in HTML:

```
<div id="navbar"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="abc.html">| ABC |</a></li> 
<li><a href="xyz.html">| XYZ |</a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

What I would like to have is more sub-menus in the form of drop down under ABC and XYZ.
Could someone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506571/css-drop-down-menu

Comment: I've had great success with [this framework](http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/). No JS required.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, Michael.. I am following your links now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362530/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-a-drop-down-menu), which points to [this page as an answer](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/), I think this ought to fit your needs quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks nightfirecat for your response

Answer (score -1):

Drop down menus aren't possible only with HTML/CSS. You have to use JavaScript.

You can make dropdown menus with the SELECT-Tag in HTML but it would have no function without JS.